# I can't drag the separator line over my NSToolbar in interface builder. Why ?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I can't drag the separator line over my NSToolbar in interface builder. WHy ?

If I open the customize panel, I can drag it there, but it is not visible in my app. And I can't drag it on the default toolbar. I can't copy paste it, like all other items.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're on Lion? The separator item no longer exists there. From the [release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html):

> **Toolbar Separator and Customize items removed**
>
> In 10.7, the Customize Toolbar item and the Separator item (with the vertical dots) have > been removed from toolbars and customization palettes, and their item identifiers are ignored.

Comment: I ran into this problem myself - I had a separator and Customize toolbar item that wouldn't show up in my app, when everything else worked fine! Almost filed a bug report lol, it's very strange that they would keep those things in the Interface Builder library when even IB refused to display them in the main window.

Answer (score 0):

Drag it into the Customize panel, then drag it from the Customize panel into the toolbar itself.